# How to install old packages in ubuntu 8.04 (apache,sambam,tikiwiki) manually

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-8.04, tikiwiki

i need to install old vulnerable package on ubuntu to make my own version of metasploitable. its part of my project. i am trying to do it manually but its difficult to install and run the vulnerable program. so my question is : can i install these old vulnerable package with "apt-get".

suppose i install a program from sourcecode then how will i start this ? as example if i manually install telnetd (configure,make,make install) then i do not find its service in "/etc/init.d" as we get it after installing it from "apt-get"

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you can get the packages, you may be able to install them with dpkg. If they're still in the repos, you can probably explicitly install them with [apt-pinning](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences#Pinning), which you WILL need to use in any case, to prevent newer versions from overwriting new ones.

With files you build yourself the best solution is to, really install the current version, see what changes it makes, and then replicate it. If you're asking this question, you probably can't write init scripts yourself - copy what the distro version has in a proper install.

I'm tempted to think that most build instructions should include essential scripts, at least in form of an example, but i don't think building things that are working and in repos belongs in a production system (which this certainly isn't)